# Replace image(s) with another image(s) from server

Tags: php

For examples, You can upload profile avatar to your profile. I want to remove the previous one the user had.

So before the query, where it changes the column "avatar" with the newfile2.jpg i would like to get the old file newfile1.jpg, and remove the previous image from the server.

How can I remove an image from the server?

Comment: Why don’t you simply use the user’s ID/name as file name? With that you will only have one file per user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use a naming convention. Something like:

```
<user_id>_avatar.jpg
```

so when the user uploads the new avatar image it just overwrites the old one.

Answer (score 13):

Well i truly agree with the "Phill", you can use the naming conventions, But you really want to delete then use the [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) command.

```
$filename = // File name with full path
unlink($filename);
```

Thanks